# Search for pattern if exist then replace the whole line else insert a new line after another pattern using SED command

Tags: linux, sed

I am attempting to write a very simple one liner SED command that does not employ `bash conditions`.

For a SED command that does something similar but instead appends to the end of the file, I use the following:

```
sed -n -e '/.*MYLINE.*/!p' -e '$aVAR=MYLINE' -i /path/to/file
```

But this time, the position of inserted line is critical, so it should be right after specific string. I attempted the following:

```
sed -n -e '/.*MYLINE.*/!p' -e t -i '/^ANOTHER_PATTERN.*/aVAR=MYLINE' /path/to/file
```

so I can turn the `/path/to/file` from this one

```
...
ANOTHER_PATTERN=SOMETHING
...
```

or this one

```
...
ANOTHER_PATTERN=SOMETHING
VAR=OTHERS MYLINE
...
```

to produce this

```
...
ANOTHER_PATTERN=SOMETHING
VAR=MYLINE
...
```

however, it does not produce the expected outcome. I tried googling but to no avail.

How to correctly perform search for pattern if exist then replace the whole line else insert a new line after a another pattern using SED?

Comment: I'm not sure about the intention of your `t` command. This jump on a successful `s`ubstitute, but you don't even have an `s` command.

Comment: .indeed, I dont know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
sed -e '/MYLINE/d' -e '/^ANOTHER_PATTERN/a\
VAR=MYLINE' file
```

This deletes the line if it contains the pattern `MYLINE` and appends line `VAR=MYLINE` to a line starting with pattern `ANOTHER_PATTERN`.
Add option `-i` to edit the file in-place if your `sed` implementation supports it.

Comment: I will test this, where to add the `-i`?

Comment: I'd add it as the first option.

Comment: The only difference of that from the append to end is the `d` vs `!p` on the first command, can you please explain what does the `d` do?

Comment: The `!p` is a negated print (not print), the `d` deletes the pattern space. You don't need `-n` in combination with `d`.

Answer (score 1):

Using `awk`:

```
awk '/MYLINE/{next}; 
/^ANOTHER_PATTERN/{$0 = $0 ORS "VAR=MYLINE";}1' input
```

With expression `/MYLINE/{next}` no further action is taken. This, in effect, prevents printing of the record when `awk`'s 1 idiom for the printing is used.
If another pattern is found, current input record(`$0`) is changed to `$0` followed by newline then followed by `VAR=MYLINE`.

Comment: Tnx for an alternative solution. I wish to avoid the `if`-statement cause its hard to read in one line. I upvoted anyway.